# Output contents of a linked list in x86_64 assembly

Tags: macos, linked-list, x86, clang, x86-64

After having gotten linked lists to work for my Lisp compiler I am looking to be able to print a lists' contents. This has not been easy. My linked lists are structured like this: Each node is 24 bytes, with the first 8 being a type tag describing the head's type (1 = int, and 2 = list), the second 8 being the actual head data, and the last 8 being a pointer to the next node. I do not know why my list is not being printed correctly. My output is `12` (I'm not printing any spaces or parentheses yet, so this would be `(1 (2`). Why isn't this printing out further? I'm assembling with Clang on a Mac.

My Lisp code is below:

```lisp
(define test_list (list_of (list_of 1 2) 3))
(display_a_list test_list)
```

From that, my compiler generated this code:

```
    .global _main
    .text
_main:
    push 3  # push argument to list_of
    push 1  # type tag for list_of
    push 2  # push argument to list_of
    push 1  # type tag for list_of
    push 1  # push argument to list_of
    push 1  # type tag for list_of
    mov r13, 2  # list of length 2
    call list_of
    add rsp, 32  # discard 2 local arguments
    push rax  # result of list_of
    push 2  # type tag for list_of
    mov r13, 2  # list of length 2
    call list_of
    add rsp, 32  # discard 2 local arguments
    mov [test_list + rip], rax
    mov rsi, [test_list + rip]
    push rsi  # push variable
    call display_a_list
    add rsp, 8  # discard 1 local argument
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall

    .data
test_list:
    .quad 0
```

Here is my `list_of` procedure that I was calling above (I have verified this to work):

```
/*
rbx = first iteration, true or false
r12 = arg offset
r13 = argument count
r14 = for saving tail address of previous
r15 = accumulator for result
*/

.macro argument_to_memory offset
mov rsi, [rbp + r12]
mov [rax + \offset], rsi
add r12, 8
.endm

list_of:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov r12, 16
    imul r13, 2
    mov rbx, 1  # 1 for first time

    recur_make_list:
        mov rdi, 24
        sub rsp, 8
        call _malloc
        add rsp, 8
        argument_to_memory 0
        argument_to_memory 8
        sub r13, 2

        cmp r13, 0
        je end_make_list

        cmp rbx, 1
        je first_iteration
        jmp rest_of_iterations

        first_iteration:
            mov r15, rax  # save first head
            mov rbx, 0

        rest_of_iterations:
            jne prev_tail_assign
            jmp save_tail  # if equal, don't assign prev
            prev_tail_assign:
                mov [r14], rax # prev tail = curr
            save_tail:
                lea r14, [rax + 16]  # save tail

            jmp recur_make_list

    end_make_list:
        mov qword ptr [rax + 16], 0x00  # 0x00 = the new null!
        mov [r14], rax
        mov rax, r15
        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp
        ret
```

And finally, here is my display_list function:

```
    .global _main, display_a_list
    .text

display_a_list:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov r12, [rbp + 16]

    push [r12 + 8]
    mov rsi, [r12]
    cmp rsi, 1
    je print_atom  # tag 1 = print atom, otherwise print list
    jmp print_tail

    print_atom:
        call display_num
        jmp after_print_head

    print_tail:
        call display_a_list

    after_print_head:
        add rsp, 8

    mov rsi, [r12 + 16]  # mov or lea?
    cmp rsi, 0x00
    je end_print

    push rsi
    call display_a_list
    add rsp, 8

    end_print:
        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp
        ret
```

And last but not least, here is my macro for printing out a string, the procedure `display_num`, and some more:

```
format_number:
    .asciz "%d"


.macro display_mac frm
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rsi, [rbp + 16]
    lea rdi, \frm [rip]
    xor rax, rax
    call _printf
    mov rdi, 0
    call _fflush
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
.endm

display_num: display_mac format_number
```

I have written so many versions of the `display_a_list` function but they all do not work. Please let me know what I can do to fix this code.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger instruction by instruction to see why it doesn't show a complete list?

Comment: Can you write in standard list notation what your list is? It looks like it is ‘((1 2) 3) but it could be  ‘((1 . 2) . 3). It’s definitely not ‘(1 2 3) which is, I think, what you would want to try first.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've used LLDB to figure out why it doesn't show the full list, and I've partially figured out why: Once the function reaches `end_make_list` (from the inner recursive call), it exits out of all of the stack frames instead of just that one. I do not know why that is, as that should be impossible.

Comment: @prl The list prints out correctly with only atomic arguments; I asked this question due to the fact that it didn't work for nested lists. Also, my intended list is `'((1 2) 3)`. I've verified that it has the correct structure with `car` and `cdr` (which I didn't include here).

Comment: I don't actually see the recursive part of `recur_make_list` . You just iterate with JMP.

Comment: @MichaelPetch My bad; I was thinking about `end_print`; not `end_make_list`. The recursive part of the printing function is when I do `call display_a_list`.